# Obtaining values from select multiple

Tags: javascript, php, multipleselection

So i have a multi-select which I've adapted with js to work without the CTRL key

```
$(function(){
    $('.select-toggle').each(function(){    
        var select = $(this), values = {};    
        $('option',select).each(function(i, option){
            values[option.value] = option.selected;        
        }).click(function(event){        
            values[this.value] = !values[this.value];
            $('option',select).each(function(i, option){            
                option.selected = values[option.value];        
            });    
        });
    }); 
});
```

and i'm using it on multiple input fields, an example below.

```
<tr class="wide">
   <td class="input titledinput" style="left: -5px;"><select title="Please select the Consoles/Platforms the game is going to be, or has, released on. You can select more than one."
    multiple="multiple" class="select-toggle roundedcorners" name="Consoles" size="1"
    />';
       $qselectconsole = "SELECT * FROM console ORDER BY Console asc";
       $rselectconsole = mysqli_query($dbc, $qselectconsole);
       if(mysqli_num_rows($rselectconsole) !== false){
         while($rowselectconsole = mysqli_fetch_array($rselectconsole, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
           echo '<option value="'.$rowselectconsole['ConsoleID'].'">'.$rowselectconsole['Console'].'</option>'; 
         }
       } else {
          echo '<option value="0">Something went wrong, please try refreshing the page</option>';
       }
          echo '</select>
   <p2>Platform</p2></td>
</tr>
```

The multi-select works as expected.
Now i would expect $_POST['Consoles'], in this case, to output the value of each selected value. But when i use $_POST['Consoles'] it outputs only the last variable to be selected. How would i go about getting all of the selected values out (as i'll need them later for input to the database).

I am open to a complete rehaul of my JS if needed, i'm an inexperienced javascript programmer and honestly don't really know what i'm doing when it comes to js. I'll learn as i go but if i've done something stupid that means I can only select multiple options but not store each individual value then please let me know.

Comment: jquery serialize(); could help.... and the key is not unique maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change the name of the var:

```
name="Consoles"
```

with:

```
name="Consoles[]"
```

This will make possible on php to have all the options into a single "array"
now if you on php write:

```
print_r ($_POST['Consoles']);
```

You can see each var selected on html page.

Comment: When you say change the name of the var, do you mean "var select = ... ", or do you mean the var as in the select name? (if so, you can make a name an array? eh?)  -- The javascript is used on multiple lists, if i change the var to consoles then won't it mean i can't use it on other multi-select lists?. Sorry, i'm totally new to js, you're really going to have to dumb it down :p

Comment: i'm saying, change the name param of html input select tag, add [] at the end of name, that will tell php that is an Array, and the $_POST['Consoles'] will have more than one value

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks very much. It's really hard to comprehend the name value (which i've always expected to be string only) as an array though. Really odd, but thanks :)